# numpy and tensorflow studying. get_dummies not working

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, mnist

I study tensorflow, notMNIST_small. I downloaded notMNIST_small to my computer.

print(indenpent.shape, sub.shape) # output: (18724, 28, 28, 1) (18724, 1)

but, I think It have to (18724, 28, 28, 1) (18724, 10).

I think 'get_dummies' not working

how can I slove this problem.

---

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

paths= glob.glob('C:/Users/doimo/pythonDataWorkspace/notMnist/notMNIST_small/*/*.png') 
paths=np.random.permutation(paths)
indenpent = np.array([plt.imread(paths[i]) for i in range(len(paths))]) 
sub = np.array([paths[i].split('/')[2] for i in range(len(paths))])


print(indenpent.shape, sub.shape) # output: (18724, 28, 28) (18724,)

indenpent = indenpent.reshape(18724,28,28,1) 
sub=pd.get_dummies(sub)

print(indenpent.shape, sub.shape) # output: (18724, 28, 28, 1) (18724, 1) but, I think It have to (18724, 28, 28, 1) (18724, 10)
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it?  Have you verified that `sub` contains the expected values?

Comment: How can I check sub? I am beginner. :)

Comment: anyone said answer. problem is sloved.

'
np.array([paths[i].split('/')[2] for i in range(len(paths))])
np.array([paths[i].split('\\')[-2] for i in range(len(paths))])
'

Answer (score 0):

before:

```
sub = np.array([paths[i].split('/')[2] for i in range(len(paths))])
```

after:

```
sub = np.array([paths[i].split('\\')[-2] for i in range(len(paths))])
```

Comment: Is this an answer, or an update to the question? In the former case, please read [answer] and then [edit] this to clarify. In the latter case, please edit your question instead and delete this.